# Error coming on creating new JPA project::: after selecting jpa version 2.1,basic jpa configuration showing error jpa 2.1 requires java 1.5 or newer

Tags: eclipse, jpa, eclipse-luna

[Pic of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfSIv.png)   Beginner trying to create JPA project. But when start to create project
    after selecting jpa version 2.1,basic jpa configuration showing error **jpa 2.1 requires java 1.5 or newer.**
    Want to know:
    #How can i create Project without Error
    #Difference of  version jpa 2.1 and jpa 2.
    #Diff of Basic Jpa configuration and Custom in Configuration

Answer (score 0):

- To create a JPA project without the error "JPA 2.1 requires Java 1.5 or newer" pick an appropriate "Target runtime" (in the drop down in the same dialog).
- Here is a reasonable explanation of features new to JPA 1.2: http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-overview/
- A "" configuration allows you to configure your new project's facets. Here is an explanation of Eclipse project facets: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcfacets.html